# Find a non-zero vector in each space

Tags: linear-algebra

The problem is given below:

[image]

My result regarding to question 1 is given below(Calculated in maple):

[image]
[image]

Then, my question is how to solve the question 2? I'm in doubt what even to do. Could someone explain me, what to do?

Answer (score 1):

The vectors that form a basis for the column space are certainly in the column space. You can choose one of these.

Comment: So would the result be [3 2 1]' ??

Comment: It is one of many possible choices: anything in the span of the column space will do.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

For the column space, pick any (nonzero) column.

For the row space, pick any (nonzero) row.

For the null space, notice that first and third columns of $A$ are equal, which means that

$$A\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ -1 \\ 0\end{bmatrix} = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Other than just applying formulas, do you understand the meanings of these words?  To get a vector in the column space, take any one of the columns of the matrix.  To get a vector in the row space take any one of the rows of the matrix. A vector in the null space is any vector, v, such that Av= 0.  That's the only non-trivial part of (2).